# MAMP Virtual host needs www?

Tags: php, mamp

I update my /etc/hosts file as

`127.0.0.1     www.mysite.com`

Then in the MAMP's httpd-vhosts.conf, i updated the ServerName as

```
ServerName     www.mysite.com
DocumentRoot   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite
```

Now, it's working fine.  So when I input `mysite.com` in the browser, it shows the index.html that is inside my folder `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite`.

My question is, when I first check the internet on how to create virtual host in MAMP, the examples never use `www.` in the MAMP .conf file above.  So what I did, I remove the `www.` in the `/etc/hosts` file and remove also from ServerName in MAMP's .conf file.  Now it doesn't work. So do we really need to add the `www.` in these files?

Another question is since I want to put the index.html inside `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/public_html`, so what I did is I set the DocumentRoot to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/public_html instead.  Is this correct?  It seems to work. Sorry for the confusion I'm kinda new to this thing.

Comment: Did you restart the server after updating the vhosts?

Comment: Yes, I always restart the server whenever I update the files in MAMP

Comment: The `www.` prefix does not have any special meaning but many people love typing it every time. You could as well start all your URLs with `littleyellowbird.` if you wish.

Comment: the problem is it doesn't work if i put just `mysite.com` in both hosts file and vhosts.conf.  when i write `mysite.com` in safari browser, i got blank page.  safari automatically prefix with www.

Comment: i set `mysite.com` in /etc/hosts... then i set `www.mysite.com` as ServerName then i set `mysite.com` as ServerAlias in vhosts.conf... it didn't work

Comment: i always restart MAMP whenever i change files.  i am using mac

Answer (score 0):

There is no need do configure the conf file directly. Just use the MAMP interface. "littleyellowbird.com" as domain and in the alias section put "www.littleyellowbird.com". 
Mamp rebuilds a conf each time you save the settings, your changes have a good chance to get overwritten. 
If you want to get to "littleyellowbird.com" even when you enter "www.littleyellowbird.com" in the browser, use a rewrite rule in the .htaccess file for this domain.
Greetings,
Peter